# Can I run Node.js on cPanel without CloudLinux?

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app on my server.

I've followed the instructions laid out by cPanel in their documentation here: [Guide to Node.js Installations](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Node.js+Installations) and here: [How to Install a Node.js Application](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application). I want to do this without CloudLinux and given Apache's Node.js module it seemed to be possible.

However, even though deploying the app in the backend seems fine, I'm getting this error when trying to access the app in my browser:

**The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application through a Passenger-internal helper tool called the SpawnEnvSetupper. But that helper tool encountered an internal error.**

**Error Details: Failed to initialize LVE library: : init_lve error [2]
The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is: Error: Failed to initialize LVE library: : init_lve error [2]**

I don't know much about LVE but I do know that it's a part of CloudLinux. So, do I still need to have CloudLinux installed after all? Thanks.

**Update:**
Tried deploying the same node.js app on a subdomain and had the same error. Then I tried to deploy it on another server that I manage (following the same steps) and was able to do so successfully. My hosting company seems to think there was an issue when I uninstalled CloudLinux from my server. (I had previously set it up to run Node and then had it removed once I discovered that I wouldn't need it.)

Comment: Can you please try out the below commands and see if it resolves the problem. 

cagefsctl --force-update
cagefsctl --remount-all

Comment: Thanks. I'm showing `cagefsctl: command not found` for those. I tried sudo as well with the same results.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of "cat /etc/redhat-release"

Comment: `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) `

Comment: Hmm, thats strange to see CloudLinux LVE in normal CentOS. I believe you should contact cPanel support regarding the Node.js error.

https://support.cpanel.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question ...
**Yes, Node.js can run on cPanel without CloudLinux.**
By following the instructions in the cPanel documentation here ([Guide to Node.js Installations](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Node.js+Installations)) and here ([How to Install a Node.js Application](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application)), a Node.js app can be deployed successfully.

In my particular situation above, I had installed CloudLinux on my server originally to deploy Node.js apps before cPanel came out with their own module for Apache. Given that I was paying extra for the CloudLinux software, I wanted to remove it from my hosting account and leverage the Apache module. During the uninstall, it turns out that LVE and other libraries related to CloudLinux were not removed correctly causing the error (not sure why yet). By simply removing those and restarting my server the Node app started functioning properly again.